# How to save Id for dijit.form.ComboBox

Tags: dojo, episerver-7

I'm writing my first dijit control for EPiServer. In my template I am using the dijit.form.ComboBox.

I have attached an event handler to the "onChange" event like so:

```
postCreate: function () {
        // call base implementation
        this.inherited(arguments);

        // Init textarea and bind event
        this.inputWidget.set("intermediateChanges", this.intermediateChanges);

        this.inputWidget.set("store", this.store);
        this.connect(this.inputWidget, "onChange", this._onInputWidgetChanged);
    },
```

Then in my event handler I have:

```
        _onInputWidgetChanged: function (e) {
        alert(e.id);
        this._updateValue(value);
    },
```

My issue is that as with a typical dropdown list, I want to store the Value rather than the Text. The options in my combobox look like so:

Value | Text
1 | "Test"
2 | "A different test"

The problem is that the value passed into the _onInputWidgetChanged handler is always the text value of the combobox i.e. "Test" or "A different test"

How can I get access to the Value instead? As I said, this is the first time I have ever worked with dojo and dijit so I may be missing something fundamental here.

Thanks in advance
Al

Comment: I know this.inputWidget.get('value') would work for other widgets, see if it works in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about `ComboBox` is that its value is not required to be an entry in the drop-down menu (and thus, not guaranteed to be one either).  Think of it as a textbox with autosuggest - users can use the menu to expedite the process, but the value of the textbox is freeform and is reported as whatever the user types into it.

If you want users to be required to choose an entry from the menu, you should be using `FilteringSelect` instead, which will report the associated store item's ID (or associated `option` tag's `value`) as its value.  As opposed to the free-form nature of `ComboBox`, `FilteringSelect` can be thought of as a menu with type-ahead functionality.

Comment: `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` definitely seems like a better fit than `dijit/form/ComboBox` in this case. Great answer. [Here's the documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html) for `FilteringSelect`, and [here's a fiddle demonstrating its use](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/MFeXn/). It logs the id (not the name) when you select a value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. And does FilteringSelect allow the user type and as they do so Filter the results? I have a list of 1500 users and I don't want to return the whole set if users in the list for obvious reasons, so as the user types "al" I want to call a rest service that will return users starting with "AI". Is that how it works?

Comment: Yes, in terms of how the menu itself works, it works the same way as ComboBox.  See the examples in the documentation (linked by Thomas).